# Create a multi array in Jquery giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to create an array using jQuery. This is a multi dimensional array. Please check the code written bellow.

```
GiftData = [];
GiftData['boxProduct'] = [];
GiftData['boxName'] = jQuery('#giftbox-data .box-data').text();
jQuery('#giftbox-data .prod-data .product').each( function(i) {
  GiftData['boxProduct'][i]['name'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-name').text();
  GiftData['boxProduct'][i]['num'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-num').text();
})
```

It is giving me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

How can I store the data? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `GiftData` is an array, so you cannot set a named property within it as `GiftData['boxProduct'] = [];` attempts to do. For that to work, `GiftData` needs to be an object.

Secondly, you need to define the object at `GiftData["boxProduct"][i]` before you set its properties:

```
GiftData = {};
GiftData['boxProduct'] = [];
GiftData['boxName'] = jQuery('#giftbox-data .box-data').text();
$('#giftbox-data .prod-data .product').each( function(i) {
  GiftData["boxProduct"][i] = {};
  GiftData['boxProduct'][i]['name'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-name').text();
  GiftData['boxProduct'][i]['num'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-num').text();
});
```

That being said, this can be made more succinct by joining the object definition and the property setters:

```
GiftData = {
  boxProduct: [],
  boxName: $('#giftbox-data .box-data').text();
};

$('#giftbox-data .prod-data .product').each( function(i) {
  GiftData["boxProduct"][i] = {
    name: $(this).find('.prod-name').text();
    num: $(this).find('.prod-num').text();
  };
});
```

Going one step further still, you could use `map()` instead of `each()` to build your array:

```
GiftData = {
  boxName: $('#giftbox-data .box-data').text(),
  boxProduct = $('#giftbox-data .prod-data .product').map(function() {
    return {
      name: $(this).find('.prod-name').text();
      num: $(this).find('.prod-num').text();
    };
  }).get()
};
```

Comment: Since all is object I guess you technically can set a named prop and point it to another array but it would not make much sense anyway, if I am mot missing somwthing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize each item in the array to an object first:

```
GiftData["boxProduct"][i] = {};
GiftData["boxProduct"][i]['name'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-name').text();
GiftData["boxProduct"][i]['num'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-num').text();
```

Comment: No problem @Ranjit, if my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.